# Exim Throttling - how to setup exim to control email deliveries/hour to each ISP?

Tags: exim, email-server, email, throttling

I couldn't find any resource about how to setup exim throttling. 
I needed to control email delivery flow respecting each ISP rate limits and guidelines.

Can anyone point me some references on how to setup this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at acl_smtp_connect acl, you will be able to write acl's in there to perform rate limiting